# Pruning weeping mulberry into wild-looking crown

Tags: pruning, mulberry

How to prune a weeping mulberry so that it has main branches with lots of curves within its crown, as if they can't decide what direction to take, like this one: (look at wavy branches in the middle of the crown)

[image]

[image]

Or, take a look at this photo from http://plantwithme.com:

[image]

---

NOTE: The first two pics are from my neighbor's yard. He even wanted to be in the picture, I had the hardest time convincing him not to appear on photos.

When I said "pruning", I meant long-term pruning (20 year time span).

Comment: This won't be tough at all!  Could you send another picture, another angle or two?  This shrub, what is it?  Is this your front yard?  Wisteria? What vine is growing on your arbor?  This is all thinning working almost exclusively below the canopy, no touchie canopy!  To be done in at least 2 sessions not just one.  Very beautiful.

Comment: Is there a way to video 360 degrees and stop to draw cut marks? Pruning is such a...major high.  Very, hummm, spiritual experience?  Doing this via pictures is just not the same.  This little tree has wow potential.Grins.

Comment: I just pulled up your last two sites...the last picture is exactly what I would love to see...happen for this tree!  Breath taking.  Sort of a long term project, your tree will become a beloved pet!  Do you see that the upper branches are selected to  keep and the lower branches are almost the only cuts made?  Similar to Japanese Maples, too. That picture of 'cousin it' from The Munsters?  That will be an awesome sculpture only if pruned correctly.  That isn't your Japanese Maple is it? Red?  Would it not be fun to use holograms? I could at least get you started and you will see quickly

Comment: @stormy I updated the question with come clarification points. I have no idea about any connection with The Munsters. Some people in the area look like them though.

Comment: The MUNSTERS?  Grins.  Old series.  There was a 'cousin it' that looked like a lump of debris.  Anyhoo, you must be too young!  If you could get a series of photos, I will try to pull this drawing application up to draw little cut marks.  Basically, you will be removing those branches beneath the top arching branches.  Not all of them, and definitely not all at once.  This gorgeous specimen, is very similar to how this tree will look...over time.  Yummm!

Comment: @Stormy, Yes, I see now, it is truly 'cousin it'. Lol! Only a hat and glasses are missing.

Comment: Funny, huh!  I have used this description for ever and I guess it might be going over most heads!  I would like to figure out how to help someone prune something I am unable to touch.  If I could, I 'd be taking the pruners and doing it myself, very bad as a pruning teacher!  If you want to learn how to prune like this...to create that picture you sent, we need to spend some time back and forth on this internet.  You need to get a righteous pair of by pass pruners.  Felco #2 my favorite.  Felco actually has blade replacements so that their tools are forever.  I'll try to download your picture.

Comment: The tears of laughter you have provided are precious.  Your neighbor...way too precious.  You should have let him in the picture!  Way too funny!  If you wanna do this, you'll be taking lots of pictures, go ahead and let him in!  I should check with my cohorts to find the best way to accomplish this back and forth pruning 'session'...I am going to check with some of my 'IT' dudes the best way to approach and use software.  One dude is a great member on Garden...Stack Exchange.  Let me know if you want to do this?